# how to make save system that save unity-specific-objects in the runtime and the values of its componenets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, game-development

I've found a lot of save systems but they just save the (float, string, bool) but I didn't find the save system that I want it to save specific objects of unity like Vectors, GameObjects, components, and also dictionaries, and lists.

I've tried a save system using jsonUtility and I didn't get what I want and newton.json also I didn't get what I wish maybe the problem is that I can`t figure out the right way to serialize the data

Comment: There are many tutorials out there for save systems in Unity; if you're developing your solution, then please provide code to show what you've attempted.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't save specific unity objects like Vectors and game objects. You need to save the least possible data in any game.

Comment: vectors are just 3 floats and GameObject and Component make zero sense to serialize since they are just references .. you rather want to serialize properties of those - which again comes down to either serializing base values, or - and this is the issue - references to other objects, assets, components etc .. what exactly is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

`JsonUtility` cannot serialize objects that inherit `UnityEngine.Object`, any type that inherits that is managed by Unity's internal code. This means that you will not be able to directly serialize `GameObjects/Components`.

You will have to engineer a data model to serialize relevant properties from the `GameObjects/Components` you want to save. Then, when loading the game, use that relevant data to re-create the original `savestate`.

E.g: Imagine you want to save a `GameObject` that represents a bullet. You can serialize the position of the bullet and it's velocity; in addition, you will need to have a prefab of that bullet that you can access to re-create it.
When loading the game, instantiate a clone of the bullet prefab and set it's position/velocity using the serialized data.

As for `Vectors, dictionaries and lists`, https://www.newtonsoft.com/json is able to properly handle as long as the collection's source type can also be serialized. (E.g: you can serialize `List<int>` but not `List<GameObject>`)

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize/deserialize your data this is the only convenient method.

- You may write your data to a file and retrieve it from there. [Check this out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUi9aijvpgs)
- You may use playerprefs [check this out](https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-use-player-prefs-in-unity/)
- You may use Could base system like Firebase/ Playfab